# High Quality Full Screenshots VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to add a feature to my program to take a full screenshot of the users screen when they click a button. I got the program to take the screenshot and open a file dialog box to save it, the saving works. The issue is that no matter how I save the screenshot, the saved image has significant quality loss and pixelates around text and stuff. This is a massive issue because I need the image to save exactly as it is seen on the users screen, I cannot have ANY quality loss at all. I tried to save the image as a jpg and a png and both gave me quality loss. I was wondering if anyone could point me towards some code or a method that would allow me to save the screenshots at the same quality as the users screen. I would like to save the image as a JPG or a PNG if possible. Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: Losing screen-shot quality when you use PNG takes considerable work.  Use the zoom feature of whatever program you are using to look at the image.

Answer (score 7):

Get the image in Bitmap format and save it as bmp.

```
Private Function TakeScreenShot() As Bitmap

    Dim screenSize As Size = New Size(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)

    Dim screenGrab As New Bitmap(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)

    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenGrab)

    g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, 0), screenSize)

    Return screenGrab

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply but I guess I forgot to mention, I would like to save it as a jpg or a png if possible.

Comment: JPG and png are not good enough to store all details of image, so you will loss the quality.

Comment: @DellDesker: You get a loss of detail because you're saving as JPEG. If yo want to preserve all the detail, save the image as **Bitmap** (BMP) or PNG.

Comment: Op is able to grab the screen but the question is to store it in high quality image. SO I mention how we can save the image in high resolution.

Answer (score 3):

For starters, JPEG images use a lossy compression algorithm so you tend to lose quality when you save in that format. It is preferable to save as **Bitmap** (BMP), which is uncompressed, or **PNG**, which uses a lossless compression.

Here is code to copy the working area of the screen to a PNG Image.

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'the working area excludes all docked toolbars like taskbar, etc.
    Dim currentScreen = Screen.FromHandle(Me.Handle).WorkingArea

    'create a bitmap of the working area
    Using bmp As New Bitmap(currentScreen.Width, currentScreen.Height)

        'copy the screen to the image
        Using g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
            g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, 0), currentScreen.Size)
        End Using

        'save the image
        Using sfd As New SaveFileDialog() With {.Filter = "PNG Image|*.png",
                                                .InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop}

            If sfd.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                bmp.Save(sfd.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

.Net usually saves the file in 96dpi, so using following code you can save the file in higher resolution with Jpeg or other format.

```
'Create a new bitmap
Using Bmp As New Bitmap(800, 1000, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb)
'Set the resolution to 300 DPI
    Bmp.SetResolution(300, 300)
'Create a graphics object from the bitmap
    Using G = Graphics.FromImage(Bmp)
'Paint the canvas white
        G.Clear(Color.White)
'Set various modes to higher quality
        G.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
        G.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
        G.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias

'Create a font
        Using F As New Font("Arial", 12)
'Create a brush
            Using B As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
'Draw some text
                G.DrawString("Hello world", F, B, 20, 20)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

'Save the file as a TIFF
    Bmp.Save("c:\\test.Jpeg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found that adding 3 lines to the above code significantly improves the quality of the image

```
var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(theRequestedAllocatedImage);

graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;


// Then call
graphics.CopyFromScreen(..)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim screenSize As Size = New Size(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)

    Dim screenGrab As New Bitmap(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)

    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenGrab)

    g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, 0), screenSize)

    PictureBox1.Image = screenGrab
    PictureBox1.Image.Save("c:\picture.bmp")
End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45788134/edit) your code format and if you can explain more then the answer will be better