# How to check if a color is on a specific location?

Tags: vb.net

I want to know, in VB 2010, how to check if a color is on a specific location?
So for example, If my timer is ticking I want my program to check if on the coordinates 507,208 the color 255,0,0 is. If it is, then the program moves the cursor to there and clicks on that place and then stops the timer. Now I know how to do everytihng of that except for the checking. How can i check if that color is on that location? I couldn't find anything on google.
Thanx!

Comment: What are you checking the color of?  An in memory bitmap, a form (and it's child controls), the entire screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check a specific pixel you can do it this way:

```
Private Function TakeScreenShot() As Bitmap
    Dim screenSize As Size = New Size(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)
    Dim screenGrab As New Bitmap(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenGrab)
        g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, 0), screenSize)
    End Using
    Return screenGrab
End Function

Dim MyBitMap as Bitmap = TakeScreenShot
If MyBitMap.GetPixel(507, 208) = Color.FromArgb(255,0,0) Then
.....
```

Where `MyBitMap` comes from depends on your answer to my question in your original post.

If you are scanning an entire image you will probably want to use a different method, as GetPixel can be fairly slow. Iterating over the [ImageData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata(v=vs.110).aspx) returned by calling [Image.LockBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will probably be the best method.

Comment: I just want to check the entire screen. Will this work for the entire screen?

Comment: It will work for any Bitmap.  You can grab a screenshot and put it in to a bitmap by using the code from here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930569/high-quality-full-screenshots-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

Another way (and a faster one) is using Windows API :

```
<Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function GetDC(hwnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

<Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function ReleaseDC(hwnd As IntPtr, hdc As IntPtr) As Int32
End Function

<Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function GetPixel(hdc As IntPtr, nXPos As Integer, nYPos As Integer) As UInteger
End Function

Public Shared Function GetPixelColor(x As Integer, y As Integer) As System.Drawing.Color
    Dim hdc As IntPtr = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero)
    Dim pixel As UInteger = GetPixel(hdc, x, y)
    ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hdc)
    Dim c As Color = Color.FromArgb(CInt(pixel And &HFF), CInt(pixel And &HFF00) >> 8, CInt(pixel And &HFF0000) >> 16)
    Return c
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim myColor As Color = GetPixelColor(100,300)
```